# Symfony: Get data from subform (CollectionType)

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a ManyToOne relation between two entities `Parent` and `Child` so in the `FormType` I have used `CollectionType` as described below:

```
class ParentType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('childs', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type' => ChildType::class,
            ));
    }
}
```

And in the ChildType class I want to get the embeded object using EventListener:

```
class ChildType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('lastName');

        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA,//---after setting data
            function (FormEvent $event) {
                die(var_dump($event->getData()));//---this gives me null
            }
        );
    }
}
```

The result I get is null although I have passed a full object to the form in the controller:

```
$parent = new Parent('Test');
$childs = array(
    'test1' => 'test1',
    'test2' => 'test2',
);
foreach ($childs as $key => $value){
    $c = new Child($key, $value);
    $parent->addChild($c);
}

$form = $this->createForm(ParentType::class, $parent);
```

class `Parent`:

```
class Parent{
   /**
     * @var ArrayCollection*
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Child", mappedBy="parent", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable = true)
     */
    private $childs;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
         $this->childs= new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add child
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Child $child
     *
     * @return Parent
     */
    public function addChild(\AppBundle\Child $child)
    {
        $this->childs[] = $child;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove child
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Child $child
     */
    public function removeChild(\AppBundle\Child $child)
    {
        $this->childs->removeElement($child);
    }

    /**
     * Get childs
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getChilds()
    {
        return $this->childs;
    }
}
```

Comment: This look like the `childs` field is not properly mapped, you can ensure that your property `childs` is named as is into `Parent` class?

Comment: yes it's mapped and I can get childs from parent byt doing`$parent->getChilds();`

Comment: Can you show us the implementation of `$parent->addChild()` method?

Comment: @yceruto I have edited my question, please take a look.

Comment: Is the `data_class` option defined into form types?

Comment: @yceruto I don't know this option where should I put it ?

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#form-data-class

Comment: @yceruto ah yes this option is defined, in fact it's generated automatically by symfony `'data_class' => Parent::class` and `'data_class' => Child::class`

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue, I tried your code and it works as I expected (showing the child data).

Comment: @yceruto really weird but I really thank you for your time and patience.Did you use a listener too to get data from the `ChildType`?

Comment: Yes, I did same as you.